# mysql: exact match?

Tags: php, mysql, count, exact-match

I'm pulling some data from mysql and counting occurrences of matches (seemingly equivalent to `WHERE foo='bar'`). However, as I loop thru the data in PHP, my count is much lower than the count in mysql.

`MYSQL> SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM database.table WHERE foo='bar';`

```
# PHP
while ($response = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata)){
    if ($response==='bar') {
        $bar++;
    }
}
```

The data might contain one or more `&`, so I want to match only `bar` and not `bar & foobar`. I suspect mysql is counting `bar` and `bar & foobar` whereas php is only counting `bar` and not `bar & foobar`. Php is returning `1210`, and mysql is returning `1783`, so it's exactly practical to manually count to see who is right…

I googled around, but was surprised nothing relevant came up for "mysql exact match" or "mysql exactly equal" x,x

## EDIT

here's the actual sql

```
SELECT COUNT(`race`) FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `completion status`='complete';
```

and the actual php

```
mysql_query("SELECT `race`,`etcetera` FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `completion status`='complete';");

$demographics=array(
    "race"=>array(
        "White"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Black"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Hispanic"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Asian"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Pacific Islander"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Multiracial"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0),
        "Other"=>array('consented'=>0,'partial'=>0,'completed'=>0)
    )
    //more
);

while ($dbrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata)) {
    foreach ( $dbrecord as $dbfield=>$dbcellval ) {
        foreach ( $demographics as $demographic=>&$options ) {
            foreach ( $options as $option=>&$counter ) {
                if ( $option==="Multiracial" && strpos($dbcellval,'&') >0 && strpos($dbcellval,'&')!==false ) {
                    if ($dbrecord['consent']==="1"){
                        $demographics["race"]["Multiracial"]['consented']++;
                        if ($dbrecord['completion status']==="partial") {
                            $demographics["race"]["Multiracial"]['partial']++;
                        } // if
                        else if ($dbrecord['completion status']==="complete") {
                            $demographics["race"]["Multiracial"]['completed']++;
                        } // else if
                    } // if
                }
                else if ($option===$dbcellval){
                    if ($dbrecord['consent']==="1"){
                        $counter['consented']++;
                        if ($dbrecord['completion status']==="partial") {
                            $counter['partial']++;
                        } // if
                        else if ($dbrecord['completion status']==="complete") {
                            $counter['completed']++;
                        } // else if
                    } // if
                } // else if $option==$item
            } // foreach $options
        } // foreach $demographics
    } // foreach $dbrecord
} // while
```

the data from `SELECT race FROM database.table` looks like:

```
White & Black
White
White & Asian
White & Asian & Black
Asian
Asian & Black
// etc
```

Comment: Sure that the code is correct? - $response is an array, so $response==='bar' will always be false, so $bar is NULL, or whatever your initial value is.

Comment: Please post the exact code you are working with. There is no way your php counted anything with the code you posted and we can't debug your code without seeing it. Also, COUNT() works in mysql, and your sql is correct.

Comment: @Ted: I posted the actual code. It's quite involved. I recycled it from another counter that works fine (`COUNT()` and the loop agree). Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: Jacob, thanks. Also, the SQL (which can't be as simple as what you posted, given the php).

Comment: @Ted: Actually it pretty much is, but I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MYSQL> SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM database.table WHERE BINARY foo='bar';
```

BINARY does the magic!!!

Comment: Thanks! Just looked up `BINARY` operator and that looks like what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the records where `foo` is exactly `bar`, your SQL query is correct.

There's something wrong with your PHP code and the code you posted shouldn't work at all (should count 0 records).

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(race) WHERE race='WHITE'` and `SELECT COUNT(race) WHERE race='White'` both return the same count :(

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL> SELECT COUNT(foo) AS rows FROM database.table WHERE foo='bar';

```
$response = mysql_fetch_assoc($surveydata);
echo $response['rows'];
```